# T-SQL ORDER BY base on MIN of a group's column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi take the following data as an example

```
id | value
----------
 A |   3
 A |   9
 B |   7
 B |   2
 C |   4
 C |   5
```

I want to list out all the data base on the min value of each id group, so that the expected output is

```
id | value
----------
 B |   2
 B |   7
 A |   3
 A |   9
 C |   4
 C |   5
```

i.e. min of group A is 3, group B is 2, group C is 4, so group B first and then the rest of group B in ascending order. Next group A and then group C

I tried this but thats not what I want

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '3' AS value
UNION SELECT 'A', '9' UNION SELECT 'B', '7' UNION SELECT 'B', '2'
UNION SELECT 'C', '4' UNION SELECT 'C', '5') data
GROUP BY id, value
ORDER BY MIN(value)
```

Please help! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '3' AS value
UNION SELECT 'A', '9' UNION SELECT 'B', '7' UNION SELECT 'B', '2'
UNION SELECT 'C', '4' UNION SELECT 'C', '5') data
ORDER BY MIN(value) OVER(PARTITION BY id), id, value
```

[OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Add the over() clause to your query output and you can see what it does for you.

```
SELECT *, 
       MIN(value) OVER(PARTITION BY id) OrderedBy FROM (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '3' AS value
UNION SELECT 'A', '9' UNION SELECT 'B', '7' UNION SELECT 'B', '2'
UNION SELECT 'C', '4' UNION SELECT 'C', '5') data
ORDER BY MIN(value) OVER(PARTITION BY id), id, value
```

Result:

```
id   value OrderedBy
---- ----- ---------
B    2     2
B    7     2
A    3     3
A    9     3
C    4     4
C    5     4
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mikael! So I need an extra keyword 'OVER' which is new to me, this is very helpful!